# Rendering elements (which can change numbers) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, interface

Currently when the user selects some tags in my app I generate them in a function, like this:

```
// Show tags that are currently used in search
var htmlNodes = '<ul class="tags">';

// If no pinned nodes, reset not found nodes
if (graphFactory.existPinnedNodes() == false) {
  graphFactory.updateNotFoundNodes();
}

// Add not found nodes as tags (gray)
for (let x = 0; x < graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes().length; x++) {
  htmlNodes = htmlNodes + '<li><a class="notfound" href="#">' + graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes()[x] + '</a></li>';
}

// Add pinned nodes as tags (blue)
for (let q = 0; q < graphFactory.getPinnedNodes().length; q++) {
  htmlNodes = htmlNodes + '<li><a href="#">' + graphFactory.getPinnedNodes()[q] + '</a></li>';
}

htmlNodes = htmlNodes + '<div class="tagsend"></div></ul>';
$('#pinnednodeslist').html(htmlNodes);
```

Basically I create a `<ul>` of class `tags`, add some `li` elements with a specific tag each, and then render it into the `#pinnednodeslist` element.

As you can see, the number of `<li>` elements might change, depending on the number of `getPinnedNodes` or `getNotFoundNodes`, so I wonder if I have to reconstruct this html every time or if there is a more efficient way to do that...

Maybe a better way is that I don't have to mix so much HTML with my code?

For instance, I was thinking to leave all the elements there and just make them invisible, simply adding a class to show them and the html content to display within... But maybe you know of some other better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First off: It's invalid HTML to have a `div` directly inside an `ul` element. Any special reason you need the `<div class="tagsend"></div>`? Modern CSS techniques usually don't need additional elements like that.

---

You shouldn't repeatedly call the getter methods in a loop like that. If they do more work than just returning an array, then it's wasted performance.

```
let notFoundNodes = graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes();
for (let x = 0; x < notFoundNodes.length; x++) {
  htmlNodes = htmlNodes + '<li><a class="notfound" href="#">' + notFoundNodes[x] + '</a></li>';
}
```

Or, considering you are using `let` which is part of ECMAScript 2015, you could alternatively use a `for ... of` loop:

```
for (let notFoundNode of graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes()) {
  htmlNodes = htmlNodes + '<li><a class="notfound" href="#">' + notFoundNode + '</a></li>';
}
```

---

Concatenating strings in loops are also quite a wasteful operation, because they cannot be optimized by the runtime environment. A better way is to collect the strings in an array, and then joining them together at the end:

```
var htmlNodes = ['<ul class="tags">'];

// ...

for (let notFoundNode of graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes()) {
  htmlNodes.push('<li><a class="notfound" href="#">' + notFoundNode + '</a></li>');
}

// ...

htmlNodes.push('</ul>');
$('#pinnednodeslist').html(htmlNode.join(''));
```

---

In order to avoid mixing the HTML you could use a [template engine](http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript%20template%20engine). There are literally dozens out there, with many pros and cons, which can make the choice a bit overwhelming. For an example I'll use [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com):

The template is placed inside a `script` element somewhere in your HTML:

```
<script id="tags-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul class="tags">
    {{#each notFoundNodes}}
      <li><a class="notfound" href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
    {{#each pinnedNodes}}
      <li><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Once during page initialization you compile the template:

```
var source = document.getElementById("tags-template").innerHTML;
var tagsTemplate = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

And then later you can repeatedly use the compiled template to render the data:

```
var context = {
   notFoundNodes: graphFactory.getNotFoundNodes(),
   pinnedNodes: graphFactory.getPinnedNodes()
};
var html = tagsTemplate(context);
$('#pinnednodeslist').html(html);
```

EDIT: BTW, nothing in this (or your original code) really requires jQuery. The last line could simply replaced with:

```
document.getElementById('pinnednodeslist').innerHtml = html;
```

---

The next step could be to use more advanced library such as [React](https://reactjs.org), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) or [Angular](https://angular.io). These are frameworks that not only render the data with a template engine, but also can (among other things) react to changes in the data and re-render automatically when even needed. This however requires learning a bit of a different way of programming.

---

Finally, if the data displayed is coming from the server (via AJAX for example), then you could consider having the server render the HTML instead of sending the raw data.